# Sandbox is not allowed to open documents in Terminal

Tags: macos

Recently I developed an application in Xcode using Swift that starts up the Terminal like this and:

```
open -a /Application/Utilities/Terminal.app /project/run_stack.sh
```

After exporting the Application and trying to run it I get this message if my Terminal is running already or I have previously started the same command from the same app (the command is executed through a menu item).

> ru_stack.sh can’t be opened because Sandbox is not allowed to open documents in Terminal.

Anyone know why this happens ? If I run it on my Mac it works fine and each time a new terminal starts on the call but when I tried the application on my friend's Mac we get that error in the described cases.

Comment: Perhaps, you should find out why an application must be sandboxed, don't you think?  Or why do you even sandbox it in the first place?

Comment: Well in Xcode i has switched off the Sandbox but i'm not fully sure if that has any effects unless the app is signed ?

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem. I ended up setting iTerm2 as the "Open With" application for .sh files and that fixed my issue. https://iterm2.com/